# Configure vite to compile non .vue files

Tags: coldfusion, vuejs3

I'm setting up a vue project with vite via `npm init vue@latest` with all options set to no

by default this creates an app.vue file to which is run as well as a components with various .vue component files.

all the .vue file is, is basic html with abit of special syntax highlighting. And I know if you use the cdn vue doesn't actually require you to use .vue files. Is there a way to configure vite to work with app and component files that are .html or other file types and treat them like .vue files when i run  `npm run dev`

I ask because I'm actually using adobe coldfusion which is `.cfm` file types and want to see about using both coldfusion and vue together. For those that don't know coldfusion is basically just html but with some special tags that can be used to perform extra logic.

I don't need instructions on how to make it work with .cfm specifically, if someone can explain how/if you can make it work with .html files then I should be able to do the same to make it work for .cfm files.

Example cfm code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <cfset showHeader=true>
            <cfif showHeader eq true>
                <h1>Showing Header</h1>
            <cfelse>
                <div>Not showing header</div>
            <cfif>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/andrefelipe/vite-php-setup Edit: Maybe this is interesting for you. You could also just have a vue frontend and have your api in ColdFusion, using Taffy or write your own api.